# How can i get rid of this?

Tags: magento2, frontend, navigation

I can't erase the Categry name because it is required by magento!

[image]

Comment: You looking to remove category name on web page ?

Comment: I just want to remove the things inside the red box!

Comment: for all pages ? Or for specific page ?

Comment: For all pages if possible!

Comment: @PiepPiper, Great I've added it for all pages. Try it, You must need to do it in XML without i dont think there is any other solution expect CSS !!

Comment: @PiepPiper have you tried my solution? let me know if still not working.

Comment: Already done! I just added it in layout xml like @ketan answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove Category title from XML add file or edit for remove from all category page

```
app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_category_view.xml
```

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
     ...
     <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
     <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
     ...
     ...
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Is there a way that i would not go to xml file?

Comment: Remove it from admin on particular category http://prntscr.com/jsdb63

Comment: Works like magic!

Answer (score 2):

Add below code to **remove breadcrumbs** from `category` pages

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

> php bin/magento cache:flush
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 2):

In order to remove Cateory Page title and breadcumbs for category pages.

You can add below code in your currently active theme.

Path :

> app\design\frontend\Vendor\theme\Magento_Catalog\view\frontend\layout\catalog_category_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" /> // for category title
    <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" /> // For breadcumbs
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove it from the category page, check below code

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove it from admin panel, click category and under **Design** section, write below code in **Layout Update XML** and then save category.

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true" />
```